# Wrap navigation in a subnavigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created navigation, where i can not make parent/child list for navigation.

I want to add a link named "More..." at the end of the list, according to available space. And then show all remaining elements as child of More...

For example if i have elements list1, list2, list3, ..... list10.

It will be displayed as list1, list2, list3, more... and rest of the links will be child of more...

I tried creating a script for this, and i think i am very close. But i have following 2 issues:

1. How to add UL around child list.
2. Sometimes "More..." is broken to next line.

Following is my JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var nav = $('ul');

       var more = '<li><a href="#">More...</a></li>';

       nav.prepend( more );

       var availableSpace = nav.innerWidth();
       var list = 0;
       var countedSpace = 0;

       $('li').each(function(){
          var current = $(this);
          countedSpace = countedSpace+current.outerWidth();
          if (countedSpace < availableSpace) {
             list++;
          }
       })

       var showInList = list; //Space available for xx no. of items.

       var newList = [];
       // Start at 2, don't include dynamically added more link.
       for (i = 2; i < showInList; i++) { 
           newList.push($(nav).find("li:nth-child("+i+")"));
       }

       newList.push(more);

       var childList = [];
       for (i = showInList; i <= nav.children().length; i++) { 
           childList.push($(nav).find("li:nth-child("+i+")"));
       }

       //nav.empty();
       nav.html(newList);

       $(nav).find("li:last-child").append(childList);
    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/Lhh019ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. How to add UL around child list.

Try creating a jquery UL object and then appending the li items to it. Like this:

```
var ulChildren = $("<ul/>").append(childList);
$(nav).find("li:last-child").append(ulChildren);
```

**2**. Sometimes "More..." is broken to next line.

This is happening because the li children are visible and stacking to the right, try adding

```
li ul{
     display:none;
}
```

to test the correct layout, after step 1.

Here is an example of the above on JSFiddle, click on "More..." to toggle children visibility

[Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/e0vz3w2e/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
var availableWidth= $('ul').innerWidth();

var totalWidth= $('<li class="more"><a href="#">More</a></li>').appendTo($('ul')).outerWidth();

$('li').each(function(index) {
  totalWidth+= $(this).outerWidth();
  if(totalWidth >= availableWidth) {

    $('ul li:eq('+(index-2)+')').after(
      $('.more').click(function() {
        $('ul li:gt('+(index-1)+')').toggle()
      })
    );

    $('ul li:gt('+(index-1)+')').css({
      display: 'none'
    });

    return false;
  }
});
```

```js
var availableWidth= $('ul').innerWidth();

var totalWidth= $('<li class="more"><a href="#">More</a></li>').appendTo($('ul')).outerWidth();

$('li').each(function(index) {
  totalWidth+= $(this).outerWidth();
  if(totalWidth >= availableWidth) {

    $('ul li:eq('+(index-2)+')').after(
      $('.more').click(function() {
        $('ul li:gt('+(index-1)+')').toggle()
      })
    );

    $('ul li:gt('+(index-1)+')').css({
      display: 'none'
    });
    
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 500px;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">a Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">b Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">c Meet our team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">d work process</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">e About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">f Contact us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">g Meet out team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">h work process</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">i About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">j Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

`totalWidth` is initialized as the width of the `More` list item.  I gave it a class of `more`, so it could be referred to within `each`.

When `totalWidth` is greater-or-equal-to `availableWidth`, `.more` is inserted in the appropriate position (index) of the `ul`.

The `click` handler toggles the display of list items at higher positions.  Those higher-positioned list items are then hidden.

`return false` prevents `each` from continuing to run once this is done.